# NSWindow scaled drawing in contentView

Tags: swift, cocoa, drawing, nsview, nswindow

I'm creating a bare-bones window programmatically and I just need to draw some lines in its content view. The size of the area the lines fall in (worldBounds) needs to be scaled down and I assume I need the contentView bounds origin to be the same as worldBounds origin so it can draw everything. The approach is to set the frame to 1/8 the size, then use **setBoundsOrigin** and **setBoundsSize** on the contentView, which I understand scales the coordinate system.

The problem is no drawing appears. The window appears with the correct size. I have a function drawTestLines set up just to test it. If I remove the calls to setBounds, everything draws fine, but of course then the bounds don't match worldBounds. Any help is much appreciated!

```
var worldBounds = NSRect()
let scale: CGFloat = 0.125

func drawMap() {

    boundLineStore(lineStore, &worldBounds)
    worldBounds.origin.x -= 8
    worldBounds.origin.y -= 8
    worldBounds.size.width += 16
    worldBounds.size.height += 16

    if !draw {
        return
    }

    let scaled = NSRect(x: 300.0,  // to set the window size/position
                        y: 80,
                        width: worldBounds.size.width*scale,   // 575
                        height: worldBounds.size.height*scale) // 355

    window = NSWindow(contentRect: scaled,
                      styleMask: .titled,
                      backing: .buffered,
                      defer: false)
    window.display()
    window.orderFront(nil)

    window.contentView!.setBoundsSize(worldBounds.size)     // (4593, 2833)
    window.contentView!.setBoundsOrigin(worldBounds.origin) // (-776, -4872)

    // Draw map lines
    window.contentView!.lockFocus()
    drawTestLines(in: window.contentView!)
    window.contentView!.unlockFocus()
}

// for testing
func drawTestLines(in view: NSView) {

    let bottom = view.bounds.minY
    let top = view.bounds.maxY
    let left = view.bounds.minX
    let right = view.bounds.maxX

    NSColor.black.setStroke()
    for i in Int(left)..<Int(right) { // draw vertical lines across the view just to see if it works!
        if i%64 == 0 {
            NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: NSPoint(x: CGFloat(i), y: bottom), to: NSPoint(x: CGFloat(i), y: top))
        }
    }
    NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: NSPoint(x: left, y: bottom), to: NSPoint(x: right, y: top))
    NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: NSPoint.zero, to: NSPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0))
}
```

Comment: This is not how you draw in Cocoa. You never (ever!) lock focus on a view and draw directly. You override `drawRect` and let the framework tell your view when it's time to draw its content. See [Drawing View Content](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html)

Comment: If origin.y is -4872 and height is 2833 you won't see anything. Don't change `contentView.bounds.origin`. See [Understanding a View's Frame and Bounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH10-SW9).

Comment: Thanks, Willeke. The problem I'm having is that the objects to be drawn have negative coordinates, how does one handle that if the origin must be (0,0)? I've tried just adding a subview with these bounds instead, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment: Create a new Xcode project. Change `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    if let contentBounds = window.contentView?.bounds {
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.5
        let worldBounds = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: contentBounds.size.width * scale, height: contentBounds.size.height * scale)
        window.contentView!.bounds = worldBounds
    }
}
```

Change the class of the content view of the window in IB to `MyView`. Add a new class `MyView`, subclass of `NSView`. Change `draw` to:

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    let bottom = self.bounds.minY
    let top = self.bounds.maxY
    let left = self.bounds.minX
    let right = self.bounds.maxX

    NSColor.black.setStroke()
    for i in Int(left)..<Int(right) { // draw vertical lines across the view just to see if it works!
        if i%64 == 0 {
            NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: NSPoint(x: CGFloat(i), y: bottom), to: NSPoint(x: CGFloat(i), y: top))
        }
    }
    NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: NSPoint(x: left, y: bottom), to: NSPoint(x: right, y: top))
    NSBezierPath.strokeLine(from: NSPoint.zero, to: NSPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0))
}
```

See what happens when you change `scale` or the origin of `worldBounds`.